# Inject jquery plus extra scripts into webpage through external js file

Tags: jquery

I am trying to inject two js/jquery files into a webpage through an external js file.

For it to work i will need to inject a jQuery framework (it such does not already exists in the page) and afterwords injecting my own js files.

To make this work, I have been trying to generate a jquery injector but ended up using one by Karl Swedberg (http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet)

When you cut everything not needed (at least I think so) out of the file and adapt it a bit to my needs, i get:

```
(function() {
var el=document.createElement('div'),
b=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
otherlib=false;
if(typeof jQuery!='undefined') {
    //msg='This page already using jQuery v'+jQuery.fn.jquery;
}
else if (typeof $=='function') {
    otherlib=true;
}

// more or less stolen form jquery core and adapted by paul irish
function getScript(url,secondaryScripts, success){
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.src=url;
    //if (secondaryScripts)
//          script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();'));
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    done=false;
    // Attach handlers for all browsers
    script.onload=script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if ( !done && (!this.readyState
        || this.readyState == 'loaded'
        || this.readyState == 'complete') ) {
            done=true;
            success();
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            head.removeChild(script);
        }
    }
    ;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

getScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js',false, function() {
    if (typeof jQuery=='undefined') {
        //msg='Sorry, but jQuery wasn\'t able to load';
    }
    else {
        if (otherlib) {
            //msg+=' and noConflict(). Use $jq(), not $().';
            $jq=jQuery.noConflict()

        }
    }
});

getScript('jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js', true, function() {});
getScript('script-20111006-1516.js', true, function() {});      

}
)();
```

But it dosen't work and firebug report that jquery is not defined. Which seems correct since i can't execute any jquery even within this script that seems to work.

In my external files U wrap the:

```
(function($, 
})(jQuery);
```

around since im trying to make my script not conflict with anything already running. But im probably also doing something wrong here as well :)

Hopes somebody can help me in the right direction.

Regards,
Dennis

Comment: Can you verify that the bookmarklet is setting jQuery up correctly?  Try using just the bookmarklet itself, and then trying to use jQuery in your console.  If you can, then the issue is with your code.  If you can't, then you need to find another jQuery injector to use (or just make your own).

Comment: The bookmarklet itself works as it should.

Comment: After sleeping on it, i just realised I inject my scripts to early.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to inject the scripts after the jquery have fully loaded.